# Store data in vs code URI when the data contains #

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am creating a temporary URI in vs code. It is needed for command vscode.diff.
I am following their example from [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/virtual-documents)

The URI is parsed via the following command

```
let uri = vscode.Uri.parse('cowsay:' + what);
```

and read via the following command (from their examples)

```
const myProvider = class implements vscode.TextDocumentContentProvider {
 provideTextDocumentContent(uri: vscode.Uri): string {
 return cowsay.say({ text: uri.path });
 }
};
```

It is stored in `uri.path`. The problem I am facing is that the data I want to store contains # in them. uri.path ignores all text as soon as the first # is encountered.
Is there a way to store data in a custom URI containing #.

e.g.
If my code is below

```
let textToStore: string = "print '1'# some comment";
// Storing in URI
let uri = vscode.Uri.parse('cowsay:' + textToStore);
```

The URI.path would only store `print '1'` in it while it should store `print '1'# some comment`. The character after # are ignored.

Is there a way to store # in a custom URI scheme in Vs code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be looking for `encodeURIComponent()`. This function encodes certain characters that cannot be used in URL components, such as '#'. More information can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent).

```js
let textToStore: string = encodeURIComponent("print '1'# some comment");
```